# Что делать, если не работает обработчик нажатия клавиш в Python Qt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt5

Мой код к примеру

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import pyautogui as p


    def openobjection(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_U:
            objectionid = p.prompt("Enter Objection id (Example: 4177334)", "Enter Objection id.")
            self.browser.setUrl(QUrl(f"https://objection.lol/objection/{objectionid}"))
        event.accept()
```

У меня также есть окно, но полный код слишком большой, так что не буду вставлять.
Покажу лишь скриншот [image: Скриншот]

При нажатии на клавишу U, ничего не происходит, а должно выявляться окно с вводом текста для обработки информации.

Comment: может потому что нажатие кнопок обрабатыват keyPressEvent?

Comment: а можно ли повторить метод также? @SergeyTatarincev

Comment: Попробуйте удалять половину элементов UI (и кода), проверяя не изменилось ли поведение, пока наконец код не станет достаточно маленьким, чтобы минимальный воспроизводимый пример поместился сюда.

Comment: @Chorkov, проблема уже решена.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_U:
            objectionid = p.prompt("Enter Objection id (Example: 4177334)", "Enter Objection id.")
            self.browser.setUrl(QUrl(f"https://objection.lol/objection/{objectionid}"))
        event.accept()
```

Просто изменить название функции с openobjection На keyPressEvent.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]